# Find this limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}$. Am I correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've found this limit by this way. Am I correct?

> Find this limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$

Let's see that:

\begin{align}
\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}&=\frac{n^2-(n+1)^2}{(n+1)(n)}\\&=\frac{n^2-n^2-2n-1}{n^2+n}\\&=\frac{-2n-1}{n^2+n}\\&=\frac{-\frac{2}{n}-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} 
\end{align}
Así,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left ( \frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n} \right ) &=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-\frac{2}{n}-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{-1}{1}=-1 
\end{align}

Am I correct? Is there another way to find it? I would really be very grateful if you can help me with this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your last step is wrong. The answer should come out as $0$. You can get the limit easily by using limit laws.

Comment: Can you notice that each of the fractions in original expression tends to $1$ and hence the limit should be $1-1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mistake in:

$$
\frac{-2n-1}{n^2+n}=\frac{-\frac{2}{n}-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}
$$

It should be:

$$
\frac{-2n-1}{n^2+n}=\frac{-\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}
$$

However, it would be better to take a factor of $n$:

$$
\frac{-2n-1}{n^2+n}=\frac{-2-\frac{1}{n}}{n+1}
$$

Hence, you will find that the limit will be zero.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Rewrite as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}&=\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}-1-\frac{1}{n} \\
&=1-\frac{1}{n+1}-1-\frac{1}{n} \\
&=-\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align*}$$
As $n\to\infty$, what do $1/n$ and $1/(n+1)$ approach?

Answer (score 5):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n} \implies \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1-\dfrac{1}{n} $ equals?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{n2-(n^2+2n+1)}{n(n+1)}=-\frac{n+(n+1)}{n(n+1)}=-\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$$

$$\therefore lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}=0$$